# URL Transmission using TI sensor Tag

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I have been Trying since past two weeks just make the TI Sensor tag transmit URL to a Android App. Please let me know as to how I can Modify the Sensortag and transmit it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't answer your question directly but have you looked at Physical Web? It might be interesting/useful. https://github.com/google/physical-web

Comment: I am actually Implementing the same using the Sensor tag. But I am hitting roadblock due to the complexity of the TI sensor tag.

Comment: Hi @Scott - the reason I mentioned that link (other than for future visitors from Google) is that you can buy beacons ready to go (which I thought might be quicker given that you've already spent a couple of weeks on it). In addition there are reference implementations that might help ( https://github.com/google/uribeacon/blob/master/beacons/README.md ). All this hardware stuff is way over my head but thought there might be a nugget in the there to help. Good luck. 
BTW the guys at Evothings are great and might be able to help with Sensortag stuff.